# Android setOnDismissListener not getting called inside onCreateDialog with AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I have a button on activity on which I am opening my custom dialog, by calling this method

```
public void openHcoDialog(View v) {
        HcoDialog hcoDiag = new HcoDialog();
        // Supply cityCode input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("cityCode", cityCode);
        hcoDiag.setArguments(args);
        hcoDiag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "hco dialog");
    }
```

And inside this HcoDialog class I have extended extends DialogFragment as

```
public class HcoDialog extends DialogFragment {

@NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hco_dialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Toast 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

}
```

So when I close dialog box, by clicking outside or pressing back button, Dialog box closes but progressDialog keeps running as **onDismiss** or **onCancel** ***is never called ?***

I am trying to resolve this for hour's now. Have read many stackoverflow answer's,but none seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [onCreateDialog() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)):

> Note: `DialogFragment` own the `Dialog.setOnCancelListener` and `Dialog.setOnDismissListener` callbacks. **You must not set them yourself.** To find out about these events, override [onCancel(DialogInterface)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onCancel(android.content.DialogInterface)) and [onDismiss(DialogInterface)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)).

So you must move your logic to the `onCancel()` and `onDismiss()` methods on `DialogFragment`.

Comment: if it "owns" its callbacks, why are they exposed to the builder... makes no sense at all